# Too large negative exponential number returns 0 but not -Infinity. Can someone explain this?

Tags: javascript

This is a strange behaviour.

```
1e-325
=> 0
```

but

```
1e+325
=> Infinity
```

and

```
-100...(decimal 1e-325 value)
=> -Infinity
```

Comment: Did you mean `-1e325`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `1e-325` is a positive number. It's very, very close to zero. It's equal to `1 / 1e+325` (well, conceptually equal). The value `1e+325` is positive, and so is `1`.

Comment: thanks. I had to think twice before asking this stupid question.